# How can I use sequelize with sequential uniqueidentifier primary key

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

I have an existing database which I try to use with sequelize. Most tables have a column named `id` of type `uniqueidentifier` and default value `newsequentialid()`.

Everything works fine, except when inserting to the database. Right now my sequelize configuration of the id column is:

```
id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
}
```

It makes the inserts work at least, but after successfully running `create` I get an object with null as id.

Is it possible to use sequential uniqueidentifier with sequalize and how?

Comment: if you want to use UUID's remove the `autoIncrement`, otherwise change the type to `Sequelize.INTEGER`

Comment: I added autoIncrement because that removed the id column from the insert statement. But it also makes sequelize ignore it after returning. I've tried to skip autoIncrement and explicitly set which fields to use, but that also results in an empty id after running `create`.

Comment: I see...you should remove the `autoIncrement` anyways since in sequelize it means INTEGER auto increment and will be converted to serial if the dialect is PostgreSQL, You can remove the id column from the insert statement by removing it from the model (but you keep it in the migration),

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible right now. I've added a feature request: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11387